# delete repeating 1:M representations in JSON files

Tags: json, bash

I have about 700 JSON files, with repeating vulnerabilities like:

```
{
  "vulnerabilities": [
}
{
  "vulnerabilities": [
}
```

This json representation is showing vulnerabilities occurring. I want to delete everything after the first vulnerabilities {} occurrence for each file. So I want each json then saved with this representation:

```
{
  "vulnerabilities": [
}
```

I have a loop:

```
for file in *.json; do
# logic
done
```

that loops through all json files currently and does logic to them.

How can I achieve deleting everything in each json file after the first occurrence of `vulnerabilities { }`

Comment: do you know `jq`?

Comment: The output you say you want isn't valid JSON at all. (Neither is the input you claim you have).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** you have valid JSON such as:

```
[
  {
    "vulnerabilities": [ {"issue":"root access"}, {"timestamp":"2021-04-19T20:27:23+00:00"} ]
  },
  {
    "vulnerabilities": [ {"issue":"something else"}, {"timestamp":"2021-04-18:27:23+00:00"}]
  }
]
```

**and** you have `jq` on your system then it's a simple as:

```
jq '.[0]' vulnerabilities.json
```

to get:

```
{
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "issue": "root access"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": "2021-04-19T20:27:23+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's also plausible that the OP's input may be a stream of JSON objects, rather than a single document. jq can handle that too, but they haven't told us what their format is with enough specificity to know.

Comment: @stdunbar - no, i have duplicates like: the above using `{` `}`

Answer (score 0):

This will delete all lines after }:

```
for file in *.json; do
  sed '/}/q' $file > $file.new
done
```

sed will quit after finding and printing the first `}`.

Each shortened file is saved in $file.new.

For example,

```
cat f2.json
```

```
{
  "vulnerabilities": ["f2",1],
  "happiness": ["good thing", 10] }
{
  "vulnerabilities": ["f2",2]
}
{
  "vulnerabilities": ["f2",3] }
```

will yield a file f2.json.new

```
{
  "vulnerabilities": ["f2",1],
  "happiness": ["good thing", 10] }
```

If you have a json file more complex, we can use awk command:

```
for file in *.json; do
  awk 'BEGIN { nopen = 0; nclose = 0; } { nopen += gsub(/{/, "{"); nclose += gsub(/}/, "}"); print; if(nopen > 0 && nclose == nopen) { exit; } }' $file > $file.new
done
```

Here we count number of open brackets and close brackets, we end if number of {'s is equal to that of }'s. awk::gsub() function permits us to count occurences of a given character in a line. This primary unix command can handle even json files with some syntax errors. As you cannot correct manually all those files by vi editor.

Comment: Needs more quotes to be safe with all possible filenames. Also, you probably need to match `}` only at the beginning of a line, as closing curly braces can otherwise occur earlier in the file as well.

Comment: It's supposed that } ends a line, no data following it, but it can be prededed by any number of characters. This seems the case for OP.

Comment: The concern is that we may have `{ "vulnerabilities": [{"name": "vuln-1", "metadata": "other"}, {"name": "vuln-2"}], "other": "fields"}` -- you don't want to cut off after `other"}`. AFAICT the OP hasn't given enough details to be sure either way what their data is shaped like.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, you are right, this code will work only for very simple json, json-like, json-erroneous file.

Comment: Consider, as an alternate answer that takes only the first JSON document in a stream of several, `jq -n 'input'`. (Not adding it myself, because I'm not comfortable answering such an incomplete question -- I don't have the level of confidence I would if we had a proper spec of the OP's data format).